# how to show bar graph on y axis in charjs

Tags: chart.js, angular8, ng2-charts

I am using ng2-charts which uses chartjs. Angular version is 8.2.14. I have to show bar graphs but they have to start from Y axis instead of X axis. Means Graphs should grow from y axis. What is the way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to define the `type` of your Chart as `horizontalBar` in the configuration options:

```js
var myBarChart = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'horizontalBar',
    data: data,
    options: options
});
```

or TypeScript for ng2-charts:

```
public barChartType: ChartType = 'horizontalBar';
```

Bear in mind

> The configuration options for the horizontal bar chart are the same as for the bar chart.
> However, **any options specified on the x axis in a bar chart, are applied to the y axis in a horizontal bar chart**.

Here is an example on Stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng2-charts-bar-template-vqunbc

```js
export class AppComponent  {
  public barChartOptions: ChartOptions = {
    responsive: true,
  };
  public barChartLabels: Label[] = ['2006', '2007', '2008', '2009', '2010', '2011', '2012'];
  public barChartType: ChartType = 'horizontalBar';
  public barChartLegend = true;
  public barChartPlugins = [];

  public barChartData: ChartDataSets[] = [
    { data: [65, 59, 80, 81, 56, 55, 40], label: 'Series A' },
    { data: [28, 48, 40, 19, 86, 27, 90], label: 'Series B' }
  ];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
}
```

See Chart.js documention for reference: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/charts/bar.html#horizontal-bar-chart

Comment: Thank You. Thats exactly the solution needed. I will implement it.